# How can you use Game Center with your Game

Tags: iphone, game-center

How can you use Game Center's Highscores and Achievements Server with your app?

Comment: [check this link from apple dev center](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html)

Comment: Why would someone upvote a question that is answered twice with a simple RTFM? :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are registered iOS developer, you have loads of information/resources available here to get started

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/gamecenter/

Answer (score 0):

I think he is not asking how to implement the Game Center Highscores and Achievements, but instead, he want to know how can he, with the development build, view the highscores and/or submit his own scores (with the development build he will stay in the sandbox and won't have access to the live leaderboard).

I think the only way is to use a promo code to get the live version.